# Is Topological Sorting trying to sort vertices or edges?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search, topological-sort

Happy easters, everyone.

I am currently learning topological sort and having a question about what topological sort tries to really sort.

The [Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/) describes topological sort in this way:

> Topological sorting is the most important operation on directed acyclic graphs (DAGs). **It orders the vertices on a line such that all directed edges go from left to right.**

This bold part confuses me. So does the topological sorting sort vertices or all directed edges?

Let's take an example which is also in the book.

[image: A DAG]

So for the above DAG, we can get a topological sort (G, A, B, C, F, E, D).

I can understand this sort. Not only the vertices are sorted, but the edges are also sorted, i.e., G->A->B->C->F->E->D, this matches the above ADM book description: `all directed edges go from left to right`

**But what if I remove the edge of B->C?** The resulting graph is still a DAG, but will the topological sort is still (G, A, B, C, F, E, D)?

If it is Yes, then I think the edges are not sorted, as A->B->C does not exist any more, instead, it is A->B and A->C. So, it this case still a valid topological sort? Can we still 
think (G, A, B, C, F, E, D) is a valid sort even if A is the parent of B and C?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can think of it as orderring of elements.

let v1,v2,...,vn be elements. and let an edge `(vi,vj)` denote that `vi<vj`. topological sort guarantees that after the sorting: for every `vi`, and for every `vj` such that `i < j`, `vj` is not greater then `vi`

Or in other notations: assume `(vi,vj)` indicate that `vj` is dependent on `vi`, topological sorts guarantees that each element "does not depend" on any elements that appears after it in the sort.

> So does the topological sorting sort vertices or all directed edges?

topological sort sorts vertices, not edges. It uses edges as constraints for sorting the vertices.

> But what if I remove the edge of B->C?

yes, every edge you add, just add a constraint. Note that there could be more then one feasible solution for topological sort [for example, for a graph without edges, any permutation is a feasible solution]. removing a constraint, makes any previous solution, which "solves a harder problem" still feasible.

> Can we still think (G, A, B, C, F, E, D) is a valid sort even if A is
>   the parent of B and C?

There is no problem with that! A appears before B,C in the topological sort, so there is no problem it is their father.

Hope that makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: So, by your description, if I remove B->C, then B should be before C or after C? Because we don't know anymore B is whether smaller than C or not

Comment: @JacksonTale: If you remove `B->C`, both are feasible solutions! [unless I missed some edge] as I mentioned, there could be more then one solution to topological sort.

Comment: Thanks amit, your edit let me understand much more clearly now.

Comment: @JacksonTale many DAGs describe sets that are only partially ordered ([POSET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)) and therefore there's more possible topological sortings. In your example, if you remove B->C, then G->A->C->F->E->D must still appear in this order. B is now only restricted by edges from A and to D and can therefore appear anywhere between them; resulting in 4 different possible sorts

Comment: @pjotr thanks indeed. Your POSET info really further helped me.